# Kotlin and reflection on properties using kotlin-reflect

Tags: reflection, kotlin, jackson

I am using `kotlin-reflect` for reflection on Kotlin data class

Definition is like this

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class TopicConfiguration(
    @JsonProperty("max.message.bytes") var maxMessageBytes: Long? = null,
    @JsonProperty("compression.type") var compressionType: String? = null,
    @JsonProperty("retention.ms") var retentionMs: Long? = null
)
```

I want to get `@JsonProperty` using reflection, but when I try

```
obj
  .javaClass
  .kotlin
  .declaredMemberProperties
  .first()
  .findAnnotation<JsonProperty>()
```

Then I get `null` no matter what I try.

How do I access property annotations using reflection on Kotlin data class (namely `@JsonProperty` that's defined in jackson data-bind)

Answer (score 3):

I just found an answer:

Using java-decompiler, it's apparent that annotations are not on fields or getters but on constructor parameters

```
public TopicConfiguration(@Nullable @JsonProperty("max.message.bytes") Long maxMessageBytes, @Nullable @JsonProperty("compression.type") String compressionType, @Nullable @JsonProperty("retention.ms") Long retentionMs)
  {
    this.maxMessageBytes = maxMessageBytes;this.compressionType = compressionType;this.retentionMs = retentionMs;
  }
```

I was able to retrieve annotations when I used Kotlin's refection for constructor parameters

```
obj
    .javaClass
    .kotlin
    .constructors
    .first()
    .parameters
    .first()
    .findAnnotation<JsonProperty>()
```